# How to use the new polimerfire to save data to firebase

Tags: firebase-polymer

I am just a rokie with polymer and I want to use the new polymerfire, but I am very confused about what is the best way to save new data to firebase, should I use firebase-document or firebase-query ? and which is the best way to use it?

I was triying to find examples on google but I couldn't find any :(, I realy apreciate any help or an example using this new components.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase-Query should be used to get lists of items form Firebase and Firebase-Document should be used to get a particular item.

Firebase-Document has "three way binding" - when the clint changes data it syncs up to firebase and when the data changes on firebase it syncs down to the client.

Firebase-Query gets an immutable copy of the data from firebase - meaning it will stay in sync with the firebase database "one-way" - data changed on the client side won't propagate to firebase or any other connected clients.